# XAML UniformGrid Dynamic Row and Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

I would like to change my layout in uniform grid according to my item number.
For an example, if there are 6 item the layout should be like this

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

which I have successfully made it. The problem is when the item is an odd number,
for example, 7 item the layout should be like this

```
0  0  0  0
 0  0  0
```

what I made is just made the layout become like this

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0
```

which is not the layout I want.

Is there any possible to done this in xaml uniform grid?

Comment: There's always a possibility, post some of your code, how you are populating these Zeros, what's the control in the UniformGrid cells. Because, I have a feeling by default it should actually behave as you expect it to, there must be something in your code making it behave otherwise.

Comment: @ArifEqbal That feeling is wrong though. UniformGrid with 7 elements in two rows will obviously have the layout shown in the last sketch.